# How to set up proxy for ios simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, simulator

As topic.

I run an app in my macbook pro iOS simulator, and I wanner config my app's requests through my http middleware.

so, How to set up iOS simulator http proxy?

I open my `System Preferences`, and config network proxies like:

[image: https://img.techpowerup.org/200731/proxies.png]

and, in my terminal, I start my http middleware:

```sh
Web server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Loading script mitm_script.py
Proxy server listening at http://*:10000
```

And then, I open my simulator's app.

But, no log appears in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator on mac uses the mac's networking functionality. Setting up a proxy server for your mac should also route all the simulator's traffic through that proxy.

Try https://www.howtogeek.com/293444/how-to-configure-a-proxy-server-on-a-mac/ as a starting point.

Comment: But this will cause all other apps to also send traffic to the proxy server, right?